# System.nanoTime for calculating Execution time and Performance Impact

Tags: java, performance, time

I use following code to evaluate performance of my methods/operations-

Question: Since this is peppered across code, should this be removed from Production Code to prevent slowing down app performance.

In one of our discussions, someone pointed out some Time calls on Linux (time zone) would perform IO looking for a file in /etc. That was causing huge slowness in loaded system for perf evaluation.

```
           long startTime = System.nanoTime();
            ...  <code> ....
           long estimatedTime = System. nanoTime () - startTime;
           double timeInSeconds = estimatedTime / 1E9;

           print ("Estimated_Time =>" + estimatedTime +
                    ":nano seconds " + timeInSeconds + ":seconds");
```

Comment: profile and check how much time is spent in nanoTime - one call typically takes 15-30 ns which is not much but could be a drag if you do it every time a method is called...

Comment: Based on other comments, it is evident there is a pre hit so I guess one should suppress it. Only catch which made me post this question was- what if we need to debug execution timings on deploying code. By turning on trace, we can see the exec timings but if it is suppressed, it can never be analyzed!

Comment: Instrumentation may be a better option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using any modern IDE you can make replacement across all your source code and replace `System.nanoTime()` to something like `MyUtils.nanoTime()` static method:

```
private static final boolean PRODUCTION = true; // change to false while development

public static long nanoTime() {
    return PRODUCTION ? 0 : System.nanoTime();
}
```

This will allow do not clean code from this metrics, but reduce performance issues in production mode.

**UPD**:

These lines of code, if they repeat often:

```
       long estimatedTime = System. nanoTime () - startTime;
       double timeInSeconds = estimatedTime / 1E9;

       print ("Estimated_Time =>" + estimatedTime +
                ":nano seconds " + timeInSeconds + ":seconds");
```

Also can be replaced in same way with same boolean trigger.

Comment: this seems good approach! So basically, there is performance impact if we just leave it on..

Comment: Sure, it is, as @PeterLawrey wrote

Comment: This would mean your entire application would depend on that one class.  Not a good architecture in my opinion.  Also it's re-inventing java.util.logging.Logger.

Comment: Logger will not protect you from invocation of `System.nanoTime()`. Furthermore, it would be very hard advice to change all users code to use Logger. We don't know is it possible in his situation. And BTW if you think I don't know what is Logger, you are deeply wrong :)

Comment: Gentlemen, if the question makes sense, please upvote! thanks!

Comment: @Rockoder already. BTW Didn't you received well explained answer?

Comment: @Rockoder In this case rules of stackoverflow say that you should upvote correct answer and check it as correct

Comment: @Andremoniy  am also inclined towards Peter Lawrey answer too since he mentioned about string concatenation which is good point. I will mark both as Correct.

Comment: @Andremoniy I can only mark one as correct. I switched from peter to yours since you did clarify about performance implications related to leaving it on in prod code and also a way to control this via flag -and also for follow up-

Answer (score 3):

The cost of System.nanoTime() is around 35 ns. YMMV.

The cost of concatenating a number to a String is far higher and the cost of performing any kind of system call e.g. IO is 2+ micro-seconds.

Taking the timing is unlikely to be a problem, but unless you are very careful about how you log this information it can cost 100x more.

Comment: In that case, if log level is trace, it should not cause any havocs unless Trace is turned on. That means, we can find out the estimated time on live production by turning trace ON (usually only for debugging cryptic issues)

Comment: @Rockoder you will still want to make sure you are not doing any string concatenation if the logging is not turned on.

Comment: For now, I am more inclined towards disabling these System calls altogether and also will get rid of printing logs. Thank you for the suggestion, I think I almost missed this one.

Comment: @Rockoder what you could do is create a sub-class which times key methods in the super class.  This way you can enable, or run a class without timing/logging by your choice of class.

Comment: I was thinking if there is a way in Java to instrument selective methods in some way. We run app with some -D flag and ask to instrument certain methods (not all since that would be too much); that way no code change required.. But this is a wish and I am not sure if that could be possible.

Comment: @Rockoder it is possible with instrumentation, though using a library to do the code weaving for you like AspectJ is easier.